# Расчет ежемесячного платежа в "кредитном калькуляторе"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть вот такой [кредитный калькулятор](http://islone.ru/calc/)

Никак не получается произвести верный расчет ежемесячного платежа, скрипт выдает "Nan" вместо значения.

Собственно сам скрипт (jQuery UI - v1.10.3 - 2013-10-14):

```
    $(function() {
    $('#amount').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() < 225000) $(this).val('22500');
    if ($(this).val() > 5400000) $(this).val('5400000');
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider("value",$(this).val()).trigger('slidechange');
    var value = parseInt($('#amount').val());
    var hei1 = value / 24000;
    $('.jawIn').height(hei1);

    if (hei1 <= 20 ) $('.jawIn').height(20);

    var valS1 = value;
    var a11 = value.toString().replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,'$1 ')
    $('.in i').text(a11 +' p.');
    var radio = parseInt($(".margin input:radio:checked").val())/100;
    var summ2 = valS1 * (radio * Math.pow(1+ radio, parseInt($('#amount2').val()))) / (Math.pow(1 + radio, parseInt($('#amount2').val())) - 1);
    sliderCustom(summ2);
    sliderChangePrice(summ2);
});

$('#amount2').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val() < 10000) $(this).val('10000');
    if ($(this).val() > 300000) $(this).val('300000');
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider("value",$(this).val()).trigger('slidechange');
});

$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 2512500,
  min: 225000,
  max: 5400000,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    var hei1 = ui.value / 24000;
    $('.jawIn').height(hei1);

    if (hei1 <= 20 ) $('.jawIn').height(20);
    var valS1 = ui.value;
    var a11 = ui.value.toString().replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,'$1 ')
    $('.in i').text(a11 +' p.');
    var radio = parseInt($(".margin input:radio:checked").val())/100;
    var summ2 = valS1 * (radio * Math.pow(1+ radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" ))) / (Math.pow(1 + radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" )) - 1);
    sliderCustom(summ2);
    sliderChangePrice(summ2);
  }
});

$(".margin input:radio").change(function(){

    var radio = parseInt($(".margin input:radio:checked").val())/100;
    var summ2 = $("#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) * (radio * Math.pow(1+ radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" ))) / (Math.pow(1 + radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" )) - 1);
    sliderCustom(summ2);
    sliderChangePrice(summ2);

});


$( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" )  );

$('#amount2').change(function(event) {
    $( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider("value",$(this).val());;
});

$( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 50000,
  min: 0,
  max: 300000,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.value);
    var radio = parseInt($(".margin input:radio:checked").val())/100;
    var summ2 = $("#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) * (radio * Math.pow(1+ radio, ui.value)) / (Math.pow(1 + radio, ui.value) - 1);

    sliderCustom (summ2);
    sliderChangePrice(summ2);
  }

});
$( "#amount2" ).val($("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" ) );

function sliderCustom (summ) {
    var max_column_value = 5400000;
    // кол-во колонок
    var k = summ/max_column_value; 
    var hei2, hei3;
    if (k > 1) {
        hei2 = max_column_value/24000;
        hei3 = (summ-max_column_value)/24000;
        $('.jawEx.one').height(hei2);
        $('.jawEx.two').show().height(hei3);
        if (hei2 <= 20 ) $('.jawEx.one').height(20);
        if (hei3 <= 20 ) $('.jawEx.two').height(20);
    } else {
        hei2 =  summ/24000; 
        $('.jawEx.one').height(hei2);
        $('.jawEx.two').hide();
        if (hei2 <= 20 ) $('.jawEx.one').height(20);
    }       
}

function sliderChangePrice(summ) {
    var a12=summ.toString().replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,'$1 ');
    $('.ex i').text(a12 +' p.');
    var m12 = ((+summ)*12).toString().replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,'$1 ');
    $('.money span').text(m12);     
}
});
```

Где у меня ошибка(и) в коде?

Для расчета ежемесячного платежа использую формулу:
сумма кредита * (процент * (1 + процент) ^ срок кредита) / ((1 + процент) ^ срок кредита - 1)

Я понимаю, что можно использовать код намного проще, но хочется довести дело до конца именно с этим калькулятором, т.к. нравится как выглядит и уж очень много времени потрачено. Всем откликнувшимся - заранее большое человеческое спаси

Comment: Когда кредиты по 100%, как-то неприлично просить бесплвтную помощь :)))

Comment: Начать можно с того, что калькулятор украден с предыдущей версии сайта Тинькофф Банк (вот скрин старого дизайна - http://ganev.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Tinkoff2.png). На данный момент на https://www.tinkoff.ru/deposit/ дизайн поменялся, но внутренности кода остались те же. Желающие могут сравнить.

Comment: @splash58 согласен) только вот я не "тот самый" банк, который дает кредит под такие проценты))) моя цель - сделать бесплатный удобный интерактивный калькулятор для пользователей.

Comment: @sergey-snegirev калькулятор ни откуда не был украден, а был взят [отсюда](http://proadobemuse.ru/uroki-calkulator-dlya-adobe-muse.html). И я лично видел подобные калькуляторы на очень многих сайтах. Предоставленный вами скрин совсем не похож на этот калькулятор, но это уже мое субъективное. Если не разобрались, то не обвиняйте.

Comment: Ну значит программисты Тинькоффа учились делать калькуляторы на том же сайте, что и вы. Логика программы (ui-slider и т.п.), дизайн и верстка и даже графика (серебристый ползунок) - идентичны. Что даже забавно - имеем две компании, которые берут грабительский процент, а сайты делают из готовых шаблончиков с помощью stack overflow...

Comment: @sergey-snegirev повторюсь, но я никакую компанию не представляю и никаких коммерческих целей не преследую. И уж тем более не выдаю кредиты под грабительские проценты. Странно получается - хочешь сделать просто удобный калькулятор, а тебя еще и обвиняют в "воровстве" и "грабеже".

Comment: Ок, Егор, никого вы не грабите. Код я вам поправил - вернее, только этот конкретный косяк, где вы путаете рубли и месяцы, отчего у вас получаются страшные нерабочие числа. Смотрите в ответах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете `Math.pow(основание, в_степени)`. А в коде у вас вот что:

```
var summ2 = $("#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) * (radio * Math.pow(1+ radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" ))) / (Math.pow(1 + radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" )) - 1);
```

Смотрим внимательно на:

```
Math.pow(1 + radio, $("#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" )) - 1
```

`$("#slider-range-min2" )` - это ваш второй слайдер, названный "Срок кредита, мес." у которого минимальное значение равно 10000. Десять тысяч, Карл! Разумеется, эта часть становится равна `Infinity` (нет, это не японская машина, это тип в JavaScript), а все остальное становится `NaN`.

Соответственно, поменяйте вот этот кусок:

```
$( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 50000,
      min: 0,
      max: 300000,
```

На вот такой:

```
$( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 5,
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
```

и будет вам нормальный рассчет в месяцах. А вообще глобально перестаньте писать код с повторяющимися неаккуратными кусками, тогда вам будет легче находить такие очевидные ошибки. Ну или научитесь трассировать код, хотя бы с помощью console.log().

Comment: благодарю за помощь. Все заработало. Клянусь больше не писать код с повторяющимися неаккуратными кусками) Хорошего дня.